# What is the real difference between vacuum and vacuum analyze on Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between:

```
vacuum;
```

and

```
vacuum analyze;
```

I read the `postgresql` manual, but this is still not clear 100% for me.

Do I need to run both, or one of them is sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr running `vacuum analyze` is sufficient**

Because `vacuum analyze` is complete superset of `vacuum`. If you run `vacuum analyze` you don't need to run `vacuum` separately. See the discussion on the [mailing list archive](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1258.1000957076%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

Analyze is an additional maintenance operation next to vacuum. It is supposed to keep the statistics up to date on the table.

> Vacuuming isn't the only periodic maintenance your database needs. You
>   also need to analyze the database so that the query planner has table
>   statistics it can use when deciding how to execute a query. Simply
>   put: Make sure you're running ANALYZE frequently enough, preferably
>   via autovacuum. And increase the default_statistics_target (in
>   postgresql.conf) to 100.

More info: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT

Comment: That wiki page seems to be a bit out of date. ("*And increase the default_statistics_target (in postgresql.conf) to 100*") 100 has been the default since at least version 9.1

Comment: And I would said 100 is insane to use today. For my case since PostreSQL 9.6, I was unable to generate good plans using a default_statistics_target < 2000

Comment: The recommendation from AWS is a minumum of 256 I believe.